# Quicksort time complexity when it always select the 2nd smallest element as pivot in a sublist

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Time complexity of Quicksort when pivot always is the 2nd smallest element in a sublist.

Is it still O(NlogN)?

If i solve the recurrence equation

```
F(N) = F(N-2) + N 
= F(N-2(2)) + 2N -2
= F(N-3(2)) + 3N - (2+1)(2)
= F(N-4(2)) + 4N - (3+2+1)(2)
```

Which is O(N^2), but I doubt my answer somehow, someone help me with the clarification please?

Comment: It looks to be correct; however it would help to be more rigorous, e.g. using proof by induction to establish that it is indeed O(N^2) in the general case.

Comment: Quicksort is not "O(N Log N)".

Comment: @YvesDaoust why is quicksort not O(NLogN)?

Comment: @kuze Its `O(NlogN)` for the average case, but its worst-case performance is `O(N^2)`. And your version of quicksort analysis does not constitute an average case.

Comment: @ilim I know that it is not the average case, I am just very curious about when quicksort will still remain O(NlogN)

Comment: @ilim let's say that if I could split a list between X% and 100%-X% (Every single time), what is the highest X that I could go such that quicksort still has a time complexity of O(NLogN)

Comment: @kuze In general, I guess you can say that if the pivot divides a list of length `N` into two lists of length `N/A` and `N/B`, where `A` and `B` have values greater than 1, then Quicksort may have `O(NlogN)` complexity. But this is a vastly different question than your original post, and I think you should ask it as a separate question if you'd like to get a more detailed answer to it.

Comment: QuickSort is best-case and average-case O(N Log N). If every partition is X-balanced, i.e. X% and 100% - X% split, the behavior is still O(N Log N) *for any value of X*. But the hidden constant will increase. On the opposite, if every partition leaves X elements on a side, the behavior turns to O(N²).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do you meant that as long as X > 0, it will be O(NlogN)? I am skeptical about that, what about a really small X like 0.00001

Comment: @kuze: even with 10^-100. At least in theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, the quicksort algorithm has an average time complexity of `O(NlogN)`, but its worst-time complexity is actually `O(N^2)`.

The generic complexity analysis of quicksort depends not just on the devising of the recurrence relations, but also on the value of the variable `K` in `F(N-K)` term of your recurrence relation. And according to whether you're calculating best, average and worst case complexities, that value is usually estimated by the probability distribution of having the best, average, or worst element as the pivot, respectively.

If, for instance, you want to compute the best case, then you may think that your pivot always divides the array into two. (i.e. `K=N/2`) If computing for the worst case, you may think that your pivot is either the largest or the smallest element. (i.e. `K=1`) For the average case, based on the probability distribution of the indices of the elements, `K=N/4` is used. (You may need more about it [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/quick-sort/a/analysis-of-quicksort)) Basically, for the average case, your recurrence relation becomes `F(N) = F(N / 4) + F(3 * N / 4) + N`, which yields `O(NlogN)`.

Now, the value you assumed for `K`, namely `2`, is just one shy from the worst case scenario. That is why you can not observe the average case performance of `O(NlogN)` here, and get `O(N^2)`.